# I have 2 prepopulated tables linked to my users table, how do I use that data?

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have a table for users: 'users' with columns 'user_id', 'username', 'password', 'state_code', 'city_id'

And 2 prepopulated tables:

'states' with columns: 'state_code', 'state'

'cities' with columns: 'city_id', 'city', 'state_code', 'zip', 'county'

I added a user and placed a value of "CA" under u.state_code
and did the following test

```
SELECT u.*, s.state, c.city
FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN states AS s 
ON s.state_code - u.state_code 
LEFT JOIN cities AS c
ON c.state_code = s.state_code 
WHERE u.user_id = "4" 
AND u.state_code = "CA"
AND c.zip = "91343";
```

The query runs but returns an empty set, I was expeting to get a query with the city corresponding to that zip code, I obviously have a data corresponding to that zip and state code, I'm still fairly new and can't wrap my head around how to use pre-populated tables I someone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In a `left join`, the conditions on all but the first table should go in the `on` clauses:

```
SELECT u.*, s.state, c.city
FROM users u LEFT JOIN
     states s 
     ON s.state_code - u.state_code LEFT JOIN
     cities c
     ON c.state_code = s.state_code AND c.zip = '91343'
WHERE u.user_id = 4  AND u.state_code = 'CA';
```

Note:  Use single quotes for string and date constants.  Do not use them for numbers.